# boost::create_directory returns exception in release mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, release

I have the below code to create a directory.

```
string path = "\\\\hilbert\\MRoot\\2017-05-04"
boost::filesystem::create_directory(path );
```

This code works when I run this in debug mode but it gives me an exception in release mode.
The exception in release mode is ***"string iterators incompatible"***

I am using the default setting provided by visual studio for my release and debug mode.

Edit: I was linking to boost_filesystem-vc110-**mt-gd**-1_60.lib in my release mode. I changed this to boost_filesystem-vc110-**mt**-1_60.lib and it started working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You schould use object `path` from library boost
e.g.

```
using namespace boost::filesystem;
path p{"D:\\newDirectory"};
create_directory( p );
```